# Can't find record from id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone have any idea of what I could be missing?

Here is my Code:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<tr>
 <%= @cId = comment.store_id %>
<td><%=  Store.find(@cId).title %></td>
<td><%= comment.description %></td>
<% end %>
```

`@cId` does return all the numbers in the collection, but when I use it inside the
`Store.find(@cId)` it returns :

```
Couldn't find Restaurant with 'id'=
```

If I print out  `@cId = comment.store_id` i get:
90 87 87 87 89 89 89 89 87 89 89 87 89 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3

Also, If I hard code it like this :
  `Store.find(90)`  It works

Comment: Check the value of `store_id`. You can try with `<%= debug(comment.store_id) %>` right there in your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `@` in `cId`, the @ makes it an instance variable which you don't need. Also don't call it `cId` but `store_id` because that's what it is.

It might be you have a comment without a store_id, and of course printing that in your view won't show anything...

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<tr>
  <td>
    <% if comment.store_id %><%= Store.find(comment.store_id).title %><% end %>
  </td>
  <td><%= comment.description %></td>
<% end %>
```

I bet you have `belongs_to :store` on `Comment`, read the guide on relations and you'll find that you can improve your code even further.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I was not testing for nil values. So I added an if nil.